# why curl_exec($url) return the empty string

Tags: php, curl

Code:

```
<?php
$url = "oooff.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

Why is the code above displaying a blank page?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And where's `file_get_contents`?

Comment: There is no `file_get_contents` in your code. Did you mean `curl`?

Comment: Try check for errors in curl request `if (curl_error($ch)){
    echo curl_error($ch);
  }`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 2):

your curl code works fine but not file_get_contents($url), it will work if you try

```
$url = "http://www.oooff.com";
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Difference is use of http://www, you can check the manual for correct path here http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php